# Import codon erroring out

Tags: python, python-3.x, g++, python-import, importerror

I am trying to use the codon compiler for my python application on mac.
I downloaded and installed the codon using:

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://exaloop.io/install.sh)"
```

Installed codon-jit:

```
pip install codon-jit
```

But when I try to import the codon, getting the error:

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/srm/opt/anaconda3/envs/my_ws/lib/python3.7/site-packages/codon/codon_jit.cpython-37m-darwin.so, 0x000A): symbol not found in flat namespace (__ZN5codon3jit13getJITLibraryEv)
```

I tried the following to resolve the issue:

- using g++11 rather than the newest g++.
- using CC=clang pip install codon-jit

But getting the same error every time. Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Comment: were you ever able to figure this one out? running into the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Python 3.7 is pretty old (it end-of-lifes in 3 months), 3.8 was released in Oct 2019.

I tried installing codon-jit using pip, running on a PipEnv based environment in 3.9.6 and it runs correctly for me.